# How to resize wordpress image to fixed height and auto width

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WP slider with costum img sizes (fixed width and height) and i need that they would scale to fixed 330px height, and auto width. how to achieve this?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As this was specific wordpress question and I found an answed, i will share it. When you add custom image size to functions.php, add 9999 to width and hardCrop to false.

```
add_image_size('slider-thumb-alt', 9999, YOUR_FIXED_HEIGT, false);
```

Comment: God why I haven't think of that!

Comment: Afterwards, you can use the plugin Simple Image Sizes to generate the changed size thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

First when importing them via the media manager you can define the native size. Otherwise you will have to hard code them like @Dan Grossman mentioned. We need more info. Site link and slider name?

Answer (score -4):

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" height="330" />
```

Answer (score -4):

It sounds like you already have a pretty decent idea of what you need. Use css to do this.

For example:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" class="image_class"/>

<style>
.image_class{
width: auto;
height:330px;
</style>
```

You'll want to target based on class (rather than all images with `img{...}`). I haven't used  WP Slider, but I'm assuming that it will add a custom class to images in the slider. If so just use your in-browser developer tools, or view source, to see what class is being added to these images, then create the css like the above.